# How do I fix the href forum link tags for my php forum?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

right now I am working on a php project that creates a forum. The forum has 3 categories each with 3 sub categories. Right now I'm trying to get the href links to send me to the correct page: http://localhost/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics.php?cid=1&scid=1 where I'll be able to create new posts, reply to existing posts, and delete/exit to other posts however the links on index.php keep sending me to: http://localhost/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics/1/1 where I get a "content does not exist" error. I was wondering how to fix this error and get teleported to the correct links.

cid=categority id aka the category for the forums and scid=sub-category id and I need to be able to go to different categories and subcategories ids. Here's my index.php

```
    include ('layout_manager.php');
    include ('content_function.php');
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Royal Reader's forum</title></head>
    <link href="/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/forum.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <body>
        <div class="pane">
            <div class="header"><h1><a href="/RoyalReaderForum">Royal Reader Forum</a></h1></div>
            <div class="loginpane">
                <?php
                    session_start();
                    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                        //logout function
                        logout();
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
                            if ($_GET['status'] == 'reg_success') {
                                echo "<h1 style='color: green;'>new user registered successfully!</h1>";
                            } else if ($_GET['status'] == 'login_fail') {
                                echo "<h1 style='color: red;'>invalid username and/or password!</h1>";
                            }
                        }
                        loginform();
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="forumdesc">
                <p>Welcome to the Royal Reader Forum, the best place for connecting to readers and authors just like you!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <?php dispcategories(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's my content_function.php where I manipulate the hrefs

````
    function dispcategories() {
        include ('dbconn.php');

        $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
            echo "<table class='category-table'>";
            echo "<tr><td class='main-category' colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</td></tr>";
            dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']);
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }

    function dispsubcategories($parent_id) {
        include ('dbconn.php');
        $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT cat_id, subcat_id, subcategory_title, subcategory_desc FROM categories, subcategories 
                                      WHERE ($parent_id = categories.cat_id) AND ($parent_id = subcategories.parent_id)");
        echo "<tr><th width='90%'>Categories</th><th width='10%'>Topics</th></tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
            echo "<tr><td class='category_title'><a href='/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics/".$row['cat_id']."/".$row['subcat_id']."'>
                  ".$row['subcategory_title']."<br />";
            echo $row['subcategory_desc']."</a></td>";
            echo "<td class='num-topics'>".getnumtopics($parent_id, $row['subcat_id'])."</td></tr>";
        }
    }

    function getnumtopics($cat_id, $subcat_id) {
        include ('dbconn.php');
        $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE ".$cat_id." = category_id 
                                      AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id");
        return mysqli_num_rows($select);
    }

    function disptopics($cid, $scid) {
        include ('dbconn.php');
        $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT topic_id, author, title, date_posted, views, replies FROM categories, subcategories, topics 
                                      WHERE ($cid = topics.category_id) AND ($scid = topics.subcategory_id) AND ($cid = categories.cat_id)
                                      AND ($scid = subcategories.subcat_id) ORDER BY topic_id DESC");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($select) != 0) {
            echo "<table class='topic-table'>";
            echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Posted By</th><th>Date Posted</th><th>Views</th><th>Replies</th></tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
                echo "<tr><td><a href=http://localhost/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics.php?cid=1&scid=1>{$row['title']}</a></td><td>{$row['author']}</td><td>{$row['date_posted']}</td><td>{$row['views']}</td><td>{$row['replies']}</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>this category has no topics yet!  <p>this category has no topics yet!<a href=http://localhost/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics.php?cid=1&scid=1>>
                 add the very first topic to RoyalReader now</a></p>";
        }
    }
?>```

thank you to anyone in advance who can help.
````

Comment: Inside `dispsubcategories($parent_id)` function you're creating the links, just edit them to get what you want.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code, for example: `session_start();` must be the first line, you can't use it after sending any output to the browser.

Comment: @triby can you give me a example of how to do that please? I'm new to php and this is my first project. I tried changing it using a if and else but that didn't solve it and created more errors. Is there some other function I should use?

Comment: @triby the session_start(); works fine however it's only the href links that are giving me errors

Comment: Yeah, usually works fine on localhost because an output buffer that is not always active on hosting servers; your best bet is to start fixing this errors now and not when you want to upload your project.

Answer (score -1):

You put those URLs here, so you can change them to default `filename.php?var1=1&var2=1`:

```
<a href='/RoyalReader/RoyalReaderForum/topics/".$row['cat_id']."/".$row['subcat_id']."'>
```

To use /1/1 as PHP variables you can redirect those values with the `.htaccess` file and QSA flag.

```
RewriteRule ^parts/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ parts.php?p=$1&f=$2 [L,QSA]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: how do I change the url for the first point to make it redirect perfectly depending on the click?